# Adding tabs in MVVM asynchroniously

Tags: wpf, mvvm, cinch

I'm developing an application with Sasha Barber's Cinch Framework for MVVM in WPF. This application shows two tabs. The MainWindowViewModel started a background worker that listens for incoming socket connections. If a client connects via the socket connection to the application the application should show up another tab.
I setted up everything well but when I try to add the new Worskspace to the Views collection I receive an error that this can only be done in an dispatcher thread but there is no dispatcher in the MainWindowViewModel.
So here's my question: How can I add this workspace to the views collection?

Greets and thanks
Knutman

Answer (score 0):

You could add a property with the following implementation to your VM base class.

```
public class ViewModelBase : ....
{
    protected Dispatcher Dispatcher
    {
        get { return Application.Current.Dispatcher; }
    }
}
```

Now you have a dispatcher in your VM. For more information, please have a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.aspx). Or you simply use `Application.Current.Dispatcher` at the place where you're needing it.

Comment: You're welcome. Please note, that if a post answers your question, it should be marked as one. ;o)